# Trying to get property of non-object Error i like

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So here's the problem when I do this:

```
<p>{{ $event->media }}</p>
```

I get this:

```
{"id":43,"location":"\/assets\/img\/space-4k.png","description":"Space","image_album_id":1277165568,"featured":null,"thumbnail":null,"isVisible":1}
```

I then want the location so I do this:

```
<p>{{ $event->media->location }}</p>
```

And then I get this nice Trying to get property of non-object error.

I dit this for another object and did the same things and it worked.. so I can't find why it won't work..

My Event Model:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use DB;

    class Event extends Model
    {
    protected $table = "events";
    public $timestamps = false;

   public function albums()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Album', 'events_has_image_albums', 'events_id', 'image_albums_id');
   }

    public function viewableAlbums()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Album', 'events_has_image_albums', 'events_id', 'image_albums_id')
        ->whereExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from("images")
                ->whereRaw('images.image_album_id = image_albums.id')
                ->where('isVisible', '=' , '1');
        })
        ->with('FirstMedia');
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Media', 'events_has_images',    'events_id', 'images_id');
    }

    // this is the media function from the $event->media
    public function media()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Media', 'header');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and guess that $event->media is a JSON string and not an object. What does `print_r($event->media)` say?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make your question easier to read, please [format your code and error output](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), specifically by prefixing each code/output line with 4 spaces. Also, it would be helpful to see more of your code, preferably an [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One guess: is `$event` defined in a loop? (E.g. `@foreach ($events as $event)`)

Comment: Yes $event is from a @foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
<p>{{ $event->media['location'] }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a JSON Obect, so you'd need to decode it like so:

```
     <?php $objDecoded  = json_decode($event->media); ?>
     <?php $strLocation = $objDecoded->location; ?>
     <?php var_dump($objDecoded); exit; // TRY TO DUMP THE DECODED DATA TO SEE WHAT YOU GET... ?>

     <p>{{ $strLocation }}</p>
```

Comment: ErrorException in 79487d15e7f32bf64b98bc29e6d7b892a687253e.php line 8:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\WWO_SOJ\resources\views\events.blade.php)